# What is this 2x10 part with a center console and two holes?

Tags: part-identification

I am fairly sure this part is from earlier than 1990. On the bottom are the characters "A" and "4". I checked Bricklink for yellow 2x10 parts but couldn't find anything. The 2x5 side with the cutout at the bottom is one level higher than the 2x4 back part.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is

[Part # 870 : Vehicle Tractor Chassis Base 11 x 2 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=870&name=Vehicle%20Tractor%20Chassis%20Base%2011%20x%202%20x%203&category=%5BVehicle%5D#T=C&C=3)